# Reindent lines in RStudio in .Rhtml doesn't indent braces correctly. Is it configurable?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

Reindent lines is a quick way to make sure your code is clean and cleans up code for readability no matter what the Python folks think.

I noticed in RStudio while editing .rhtml files for knitting into html reports, that the code indent aligns the braces ({}) incorrectly.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <!--begin.rcode

    #not idiomatic indentation
    for( i in (1:10)){
      a=i+1  
      } # ☹

    #ideal indentation
    for( i in (1:10)){
      a=i+3
    } # ☺

    end.rcode-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Is there a special character to fix this?  A config file? A different build of RStudio?

Thank you for your hints and tips.

Comment: I see the same behavior: in a .R script, I get the "ideal" indentation, but in Rhtml and Rmd I see the "not idiomatic" indentation. The fact that this is inconsistent across code types suggests that it's a bug, and should be reported via the [support page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/topics).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I posted it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RStudio developers confirmed it was a bug.